# Remove the header of Drawer navigator - React native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I'm using drawer navigator to create a menu by react native I want to remove the header and keep just the bar icon so I tried to turn the backgroundColor into transparent but it doesnt work.

the code is bellow:

```
<Drawer.Navigator      
  drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
    <Drawer.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={HomeScreen}
      options={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        },
      }}
    />
```

[image]

Comment: What are the styles that get applied to the header right now?

Comment: Do you want the 3 horizontal bar icon (left hand side of the header) to display only?

Comment: @Gandzal yeah exactly

Comment: @FabianS. I didn't applied any StyleSheet to the header

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by adding screenOption to the Drawer.navigator

```
screenOptions={{
  headerShown: true,
  headerTransparent:true
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello i had the same exact problem i solved it with adding

```
screenOptions={{
  headerShown: false
}}
```

to Drawer.navigator